# Cannot locate the Python samples module referenced in Google's sample code

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to work through the Python code example on [the google page that shows examples of how to script the export of data from a Big Query table in csv format.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#pythonsample)

At the top of the example script I have the following two import statements:

```
from samples import auth
from samples import poll_job
```

However, I've been unable to locate any 'samples' modules for Python.  Any attempt to run a version of the script results in an error such as "Import Error: cannot import name auth"

Can anyone tell me where to locate the samples modules, or if there is another module that provides the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There is a giant red button on that site that says Download Project ZIP - The files you are looking for are in there, along with numerous other files.

Comment: Robert, I had looked at the files in the ZIP previously, but being new to Python hadn't put the concepts together.  Thanks for focusing my attention there.  It all suddenly clicked for me.

Comment: @DavidLee Glad to hear it :) We all need a nudge sometimes; and in my case sometimes the nudge needs to be a swift kick in the ascii